# I think my if else statement is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

This is the Code

```
Age = int(input("Enter Your Age: "))
    if (Age > 18):
        print("Your are 18+")
        pass
    if (Age == 18):
        print("Your are 18")
        pass
    else:
        print("You are below 18")
```

This is the Output

```
Enter Your Age: 20
Your are 18+
You are below 18
```

1. When `Age > 18` it should print `"Your are 18+"`
2. When `Age == 18` it should print `"Your are 18"`
3. When `Age < 18` it should print `"Your are below 18"`
   What is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `if elif else` ladder. Don't use `pass`. `pass` is when you do nothing inside a branching condition.

In your code,

1. Given input 20, the first `if` gets evaluated. As it's true, the print statement gets executed.
2. Second `if` will get executed. As it's `false`, the condition is false, it won't go inside the `if` block.
3. Next it will go to `else` block. Because the `else` is tied with the second `if` the context for this is only second `if`

```
    Age = int(input("Enter Your Age: "))
    if (Age > 18):
        print("Your are 18+")
        
    elif (Age == 18):
        print("Your are 18")
        
    else:
        print("You are below 18")
```

If you want to do with `if/else` only

```
Age = int(input("Enter Your Age: "))
if (Age > 18):
    print("Your are 18+")
else:
    if (Age == 18):
        print("Your are 18")    
    else:
        if (Age < 18):
            print("You are below 18")
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do it with an if-else statement? Could you explain what is the error here?

Answer (score 1):

change your second if statement to elif. It doesn't work currently because else is comparing to your second if condition.

Comment: Actually it works when I use elif. But I want to know why it is not working with if-else? In other programming languages like C, C++, Java, it actually works. Why it's not working with python?